# MediaRecorder - The Pause and resume events don't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, mozilla, mediarecorder

I'm trying to wrap my head around the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder), so I coded a simple web app that starts, pauses, resumes and stops audio recording. The code seems to work fine, until I tested it out in Firefox ( The latest version ).

[[ The full code is here ]](https://justpaste.it/45617)

**Javascript code:**

```
var mediaRecorder = null,
constraints = { audio: true };


function onSuccess( stream ) {
   mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder( stream );

   function getStatus() {
      alert('The mediaRecorder is ' + mediaRecorder.state);
   }

   mediaRecorder.onstart = getStatus;
   mediaRecorder.onpause = getStatus;
   mediaRecorder.onresume = getStatus;
   mediaRecorder.onstop = getStatus;
}

var onError = function(err) {
   console.log('Error: ' + err);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

**Html code :**

```
<button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.start()">Start</button>
<button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.pause()">Pause</button>
<button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.resume()">Resume</button>
<button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.stop()">Stop</button>
```

I figured out that, in Firefox, when clicking pause, the mediaRecorder is actually paused but it doesn't fire the pause event ( onpause ), and the same thing for resume.

**Question:** Is there a way to fix this problem ?

Comment: somewhat known bug, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363915

Comment: @PhilippHancke Thank you so much, that makes sense . The bug was reported a year ago !?!, idk why they didn't fix it though!

Comment: @PhilippHancke It seems that this MediaRecorder is very unstable .

Comment: @CryptoBird because it stumbled upon an unclear area of [the spec](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-record/issues/123).

Comment: @Dexter You are AWESOME, the picture now is crystal clear.

Comment: @PhilippHancke Congratulations guys, the bug has been fixed [bug 1458538](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1458538)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a [**bug** in Mozilla Firefox](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363915), and as a workaround, I found this awesome cross-browser library and it worked for me like a charm : [**Audrec**](https://github.com/BadrHaimeur/Audrec)

Comment: Congratulations guys, the bug has been fixed [bug 1458538](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1458538)